# how to stop hackers from any spoofing?

Tags: arp-spoofing

My PC and network, internet are under attack by hackers.
I have used XARP a software that shows the attacks, but cannot stop them.
The professional version claims it can, by buying XARP PRO.
I am disabled, cannot afford to buy software, I barely survive with what I get.
Is there any free software to stop hackers?
Since it is a world (planet Earth) problem, if we supply the defense against hackers for free, we may be able to stop them.

Comment: Please be more precise with the kind of attacks.

Comment: I don't think the kind of attack matters here, @SEJPM. The question is clearly off-topic as OP is asking for a product recommendation and nothing more.

Comment: @That1Guy Well I have the intuition that the OP wants advice. If he specifies the kind of attack (and is generally more specific) and edites the product recommendation out of the question, I think it may be on-topic.

Comment: Currently this question has nowhere near enough info. What type of attacks? You say spoofing attacks - but this doesn't really mean anything without context. Please edit your post with more info.

Comment: @SEJPM You make a fair point, but as-is this question should be closed. Should OP make the edits you suggest, the community can vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for you, hacking attacks can be complex and are constantly changing. I would be *very* suspicious of any company that claims that a single piece of software can "stop attacks" - entire teams of the best security engineers on the planet don't even make that claim!

Chances are, if this is a typical home-network setup, you have some viruses on your machine that are letting the attackers through. Without knowing more about your situation, I would say that your best bet is to rebuild your system(s), being very careful about what you put on them. Wipe your computer(s) hard drive(s), reinstall the operating system(s), reinstall any programs that you use (being careful about where you download the setup.exe's from), install an anti-virus and keep it up to date, do some reading about the security settings on your router and turn them on, etc.

While you're at it, you could read some blogs with DOs and DON'Ts of safe browsing practices so you don't end up downloading a whole new set of viruses and wind up right back in the same boat.

Answer (score -2):

Buy a simple NAT router. Even if you have one PC, you still should use a simple NAT router between computer and internet, as a basic protection. That will drop all incoming attacks in the computer.

About the attacks you see in XARP, I suspect these are just automated portscans done by malware on other machines out on the internet. Those won't hurt you provided you do have some firewall, like a NAT router, blocking incoming requests.

If you have a NAT router or firewall employed, then the only way to get hacked would be visiting a infected web page, opening a file, mail or something, or clicking on something suspicious.

Comment: I don't think the original question has enough information to give an accurate answer. This can be more misleading than helpful given the question's vagueness.

Comment: @d1str0 I suspect the OP is just a newbie who just saw a lot of port scans (detected as "attacks") in some trial security software, and want to know how to protect against this. And then I say, just buy a NAT router, any model or make, doesn't matter, they all give similiar protection, to just get rid of these attacks, and avoid getting hacked because one of these attacks slipping through.

Comment: You're offering advice based on a loose assumption and suggesting they spend money. As OP stated, he doesn't have much money to live off of. Not understanding the OP's question can be more damaging if you're suggesting he spends what little money he has.

Comment: Actually XARP is a software used to detect ARP spoofing, so it's definitely not just port scans.

Comment: ARP spoofing typically require physical proximity, so perhaps the tool is mistaken or the solution can be as simple as changing the default wifi password